# Android Studio - Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' C:\Users\myaccountname\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Tags: android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9fpj.png

[image: 1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9fpj.png]

Anyone know how to solve this issue? i have been stuck for few hours

Comment: click on that blue sign resulting in error resolving..

Comment: ok checking the solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error itself saying that `Failed to find target android-25`

So simply install android platform 25 by going to SDK manager.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok i will give it a try, installing right now

Comment: Hi Shylendra Madda, need your help to check is my platform 25 install in the correct location ? (at below comment)

Comment: Where is your comment?